# TypeScript: ale vs tsuquyomi?

Tags: plugin-ale, filetype-typescript

[Ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) and [`tsuquyomi`](https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi) both seem to be Vim Language Servers that can interface with `tsserver`. Because ale supports multiple languages, is there any reason to use tsuquyomi moving forward?

I'm an old time `tsuquyomi` user looking at all the new kids using Ale and wondering if ale isn't just a better replacement?